# How to search the contents of a list whilst at a break point in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a asp.net / c# web site that I am debugging, there is a list variable that I want to break at and search the contents of the list to find a specific entry. When I hover over the list whilst at the break I can see the individual entries fine and scroll through them, but there are 50,000 entries and I want to search the list for a specific entry.

Is there an easy way to search the contents of the list from the IDE whilst at a break point? I'm using VS 2015 Community edition

Comment: Have you tried Immediate Window?

Comment: How would you search for the entry if you could use code? The [quick-watch window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx) can execute any code but not lambda expressions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, support for lambdas in the immediate window were introduced in VS2015.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: good to know, unfortunately i'm stuck with VS 2010.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Hugs? ;)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: no, thanks, i can bear this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Immediate Window is made for this. [Link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Make a query in a separate variable after the breakpoint such as if you have some filtering logic

```
var item = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "myid");
```

Now hover over `item` and you will see the individual properties.

Another way would be to use the Immediate window as @Daniel suggested.

While in the Immediate window and debugging  you can access variables by index such as `myList[3]` for 4-th element. If you don't know which is the index of the value in the array you can use the first approach since you cannot have lambda expressions in the Immediate window unfortunately.

Edit :  Thanks to Moo-Juice who suggested that
 support for lambda expressions in the immediate window has been introduced in VS2015. If you are using that version you can ease your life a lot.

Comment: He is using the debugger and don't want to change the code, at least not if it's possible without (i assume). You cannot use lambdas in the quick watch window.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Unless he is using VS 2015

Comment: @Daniel I was about to mark your answer as correct but you've deleted it! Immediate window was the key, thanks

Comment: Didnt delete it, it was just a comment...I can make it an answer for the future :-)